# How to provide default value in parameter?

Tags: javascript

```js
function x({ name = 'abc' }) {
  console.log(name);
}

x({ name: null })
```

How to provide default value for above case which handles all falsey value for name? I was expecting that when `name: null` will be replaced by `abc` but apparently not the case? It's only working in the below case

```js
function x({ name = 'abc' }) {
  console.log(name);
}

x({  })
```

Wondering if it's possible to provide default value for all falsey value? Of course we can check for the condition explicitly but wondering if there is any alternatives

Comment: what about `name = name || 'abc'`? As long as name is falsey it will work, though it will work with `''` as well, which might not be intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default parameter values are only applied when the value is `undefined`. You'd have to implement such logic yourself.

```js
function x({name}) {
  if (!name) {
    name = 'abc';
  }
  console.log(name);
}

x({ name: null })
```

Comment: So, what's happen if `name` contains value `false` (`x({ name: false })`)?

Comment: @TânNguyễn: Correct, means we can't really rely on `!name` but to explicitly handle specific falsey value instead

Answer (score 2):

`null` is intentional, `undefined` is not.

In other words, providing null means the value is `null`, so 'abc' will not be set as the default value.

This should do the trick:

```js
function x({ name }) {
   !(!!name) && (name = 'abc'); 
      
   console.log(name);
}
    
x({ name: null })
```

Comment: In other words default value for parameters are only meant for undefined instead of falsey values?

Comment: Arguably you can also intentionally pass `undefined` though ;)

Comment: @FelixKling: True that! now default value for parameters don't seems to be really that helpful ha!

Answer (score 0):

How does redefining suits you in case, when the value was null?

```js
function x({ name }) {
  name = name ? name : 'abc';
  console.log(name);
}

x({ name: null });
x({ name: 'asd' });
```